# How can I save player's score to Facebook with default permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-permissions

I'm trying to integrate Facebook with my game in a very simple way - I want player to be able to see results (scores) of his friends.

Getting friends results is easy - you can just use HTTP GET request to "/APP_ID/scores" to get a list of all friends playing this game and their scores.
You can do this with the default Facebook permissions with no problem.

But how do you update these scores? According to Facebook docs you have to have *publish_actions* permission in order to use  HTTP POST request to "/USER_ID/scores".

Which requires Facebook review and approval + is a total overkill since I don't really need any real publishing privileges - I just want to update the score of the player in my game. It seems strange that some special permissions are required. Am I missing something?

Also, I have checked popular 1010 game which is installed on my device. They have facebook scores implemented, but it does not seem that they have requested any publish permissions from me - here is a screenshot of app settings in my Facebook account (they have *games_activity* permission, but acoording to docs it is for reading only):
[image: app settings]

Comment: You need publish_actions. They probably ask when it is needed

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite clear from the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements

> Both the Scores API and Achievements API are only available for apps that are categorized as **Games**.
>
> Because these API let developers write information about player game state to the Graph API, they both require `publish_actions` permissions, which is subject to **Login Review**. To retrieve Score and Achievement information about a player's friends, both the player and their friends need to grant the `user_friends` permission.

Comment: Yes, I have read this, but it seems very odd to me. I understand why I would need to get permission to publish something to random user's profile. But it seems that permission to update app profile should be given to this app by default.

Comment: There is no such thing as an app profile. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Maybe profile is not the right word. I'm talking about this - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application - there are lots of things you can update there without publish rights (which makes sense - it is your app, so you should already have permission to update it).